# Redux + WPLM как перевести содержимое полей?

Tags: wordpress, redux

Есть произвольные поля, созданные при помощи Redux. Как переводить содержимое полей на разные языки, плагином WPLM ??? как на эти поля поставить переключатель языков?

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте почитать советы поддержки здесь: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wpml-redux-framework-real-estate-7-incompatibility/